# Importing Python files from inside folders

Tags: osx, python, python3

On Mac OS X, I can import a .py file named test inside the directory `dir` by running

```
import dir.test
```

However, on Debian (specifically Raspian) this does not work. What is the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the package file `__init__.py` in the directory `dir`.

Comment: Thank you! I am used to not having to do that in OS X.